# Simply alerting JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="test">
        <meta name="author" content="test">
        <!--Google's CDC for jQuery.-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function() { 
     $.getJSON('http://status.leagueoflegends.com/shards?api_key=secretcode', function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
});
```

When I try to alert this.

https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=secretcode

It works.

But this. http://status.leagueoflegends.com/shards?api_key=secretcode

Doesn't work.

PS. secret code is the API key they gave us.

Comment: request the url on your browser directly to know what went wrong.

Comment: Look in your console for errors. Is your website running HTTPS?

Comment: You're likely getting errors back and it's not calling the success handler. Add an error handler to your request.

Comment: Sorry, new to this. How do I check for errors?

Comment: I tried the URL and I got this.

http://puu.sh/c2GnG/0a556a8895.png

Answer (score 0):

As my reputation is currently to low, I've to answer directly and can't add a comment. I hope I'm not bothering anyone with that.

The $.getJSON - function allows you to append multiple callback functions. Those functions are '.done()', '.always()', and '.fail()'.

```
$.getJSON('http://status.leagueoflegends.com/shards?api_key=secretcode', function (data) {
})
.done(function( data ) {
    alert( data );
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
  alert( errorThrown );  
});
```

See more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Now you should be able to get a more detailed error message. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for that, learned something new. :)

It just shows an empty alert box? ._.